# Decomposition Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

**Theorem**

Let $V$ a $K$-vector space of finite dimension, $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_k(V), f_1,\dots f_t \in K[x]$ coprimes by pairs, $V_i=\operatorname{Ker}(f_i(\phi))$ and $f=f_1\dots f_t. $ If $f(\phi) = 0$ then:

a) $V_i$ is a $\phi\text{-invariant} $ subspace of $V$, for each $i\leq t$;

b)  $V = V_1\bigoplus \dots \bigoplus V_t;$

c) $B = B_1 \cup \dots\cup B_t $ is a base of $V_i$, for each $i\leq t$;

d) $M_\phi(B)=M_{\phi_1}(B_1)\bigoplus\dots\bigoplus M_{\phi_t}(B_t)$ where $\phi_i$ is the restrinction of $\phi $  to $ V_i$.

Is this proof correct for the theorem? Is there a better way to prove it? These are my teacher notes but I don't understand it very well.

---

**Proof**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can understand this proof.